# Access to Uber Driver API

Tags: uber-api

I have just submitted an application for access to the **[Uber Driver API](https://developer.uber.com/docs)** including details of my intended use of the service for the benefit of drivers.

Uber's response was "*we will let you know if we think there is a fit*".

> Does anyone know if this is literally true? Or is there some period of
>   time after which I assume that my application has been rejected?

Better still, is there a way to find out a rejection status and appeal?

Comment: There is not any current method of finding out status. If you do not hear back within a month, it is likely you were not selected and would not be selected until a future relaxation of driver API access.

Answer (score 0):

Uber as of now don't provide a way to track the progress of your application to access the Driver API, If your use case is really helpful for the driver and Uber also think that is, along with other parameters like number of current user base etc., they might consider.
You can always checkout the [developer support page](https://developer.uber.com/support)